# Convert dataframe to JSON with Spark - performance issues

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe

I am using the following statement to convert spark's dataframe to json format:
      val res = resultDF.toJSON.collect.mkString(",")

however it's performance seems to be bad even for small dataframe (~10 sec for dataframe with one cell). I wonder if there is a way to make it faster? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's faster to write a json and after load:

```
df.write.json("/my_path")
```

and then you read that file